# Decrypted String has valid and invalid characters

Tags: java, android, base64, bouncycastle, boringssl

I'm decrypting an RSA encrypted base64 encoded string using the following code. However the decrypted string has some *invalid characters* prepended to real string. I've been trying to figure out what might be causing this garbage data to appear but my limited expertise in this are limiting me.

The data is encrypted using the following commands using openssl in terminal.

**OpenSSL Commands used:**

```
openssl genrsa -out priv_key.pem 2048  
openssl rsa -pubout -in priv_key.pem -out pub_key.pem 
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in userdata.json -out user_encrypted_with_pub_key -inkey pub_key.pem –pubin
```

The only thing that I'm doing programmatically is to decode the data encrypted using the above commands. I'm using bouncyCastle latest release.

**Code:**

```
decipherString(priv, decodeBase64(base64StringBuilder.toString()).toByteArray());

private static void decipherString(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] encodedStringData) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(encodedStringData);
            Timber.w("Deciphered text is: %s", new String(dectyptedText, "UTF-8"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

T1.O�Y1�{�l�M�X�`�������/*9���Z��yt�戔��Eo��Z3���~7Aܴ�rtj)j��x*')��e�/�$iJ���;���1&��I�U�#�$����}�C�����4P��E�-ρ�����?�wQ���Z�n�b��Py�%�>�I�X����TqDv�_���?��{ "ssid": "PT", "password": "XYZ123" , "security": "WPA2" }

Comment: try ASCII encoding

Comment: Tried that as well but it still gives the same output. I tried without providing any charset as well for the decrypted string and still the same output. But decrypting using decrypt command from terminal gives proper decrypted string

Comment: can you tell what the output on the cli is?

Comment: `{ "ssid": "PT", "password": "XYZ123" , "security": "WPA2" }` is the output on the CLI but when doing with code, it has prepended garbage data

Comment: I can't find your other question at the moment, but the same applies... We need more information, like the public and private key and a hex dump of the of the plain text and cipher text. There is no way anyone can test what you are doing.

Comment: @jww I can provide you public and private key but I've no idea about cipher text. The plain text is: `{ "ssid": "PT", "password": "XYZ123" , "security": "WPA2" }`

Comment: 1. The decryption failed so the result is random binary bytes and they are not representable as a character string. 2. Provide the encrypted data hexadecimal encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, ever, do this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

Always specify the full transformation string: "*algorithm/mode/padding*". Failure to do so will result in non-portable code, because the defaults are provider-specific. In your case the defaults are equivalent to something like

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
```

But that isn't what you need here. `openssl rsautl` by default uses PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption padding, so what you need is

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Comment: Super awesome! How did you know which parameters were needed? I would love to learn some basics about this library from a noob friendly source.